# Filtering out negative numbers using scanf

Tags: c++, scanf, unsigned

my aim is to scan for some positive-only `a`, if negative number is entered, the function should print error:

```
if ( scanf("%u %lf", &a, &b) != 2 ) {
    //error
}
```

Now the theory is that `scanf` returns successful writing attempts, so if I enter a negative number, `scanf` shouldn't return 2. My theory seems to be incorrect, why?

Obviously I could simply `scanf` `%d` and then check whether `%d` is negative but right now I'm curious why my initial theory is incorrect. So is there a way without scanning and then comparing?

Comment: Did you read the [`scanf` documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf), primarily the *Return Value* section? Did you also check the value of `a`?

Comment: Yes, I've read it."On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled." So basically if it successfully scans for two arguments, it will return 2. So I thought that if I give `scanf` a negative number when it expects `unsigned int`, it shouldn't scan successfully.

Comment: There's more than one sentence in that section: *"This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.

If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.

If an encoding error happens interpreting wide characters, the function sets errno to EILSEQ."*

Comment: It could also be converting the given signed integer into an unsigned integer, you should check the value of `a`.

Comment: I thought assigning a negative number to unsigned int would yield an error, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your theory doesn't work because scanf doesn't fail or doesn't refuse to copy the user input to the memory address specified even if a signed number is entered when an unsigned number is expected. Therefore, as per the [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) documentation, scanf will return the number of items copied to the provided memory address.

Comment: Why doesn't it fail? Does it simply convert `signed int` into `unsigned int`?

Comment: It is an undefined behavior. It might get converted to a positive number (unsigned) or it may not.

Answer (score 2):

> My theory seems to be incorrect, why?

When `%u` is used as the format spefifier, `scanf` expects (from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf):

> The format of the number is the same as expected by `strtoul()` with the value 10 for the base argument.

[`strtoul` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) says this about negative numbeers:

> If the minus sign was part of the input sequence, the numeric value calculated from the sequence of digits is negated as if by unary minus in the result type, which applies unsigned integer wraparound rules.

Hence `%u` does not fail even when you enter a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` still succeeds (and increments the return value) if the input is not the right *type* of number.

For example, if `scanf("%u", &my_unsigned_int);` reads the text "-1", it will return 1 and `my_unsigned_int` will be written to like `my_unsigned_int = (unsigned int) -1;`

This will also be the case if they enter a decimal value - it will be assigned to your int field with a type cast.  It doesn't look like you rule out floats, so you probably just want to `scanf("%f", &some_float);` and then check the value of `some_float`.